# yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, routes, frontend, yii2-advanced-app

We have created the advanced yii app and changed the urls to clean urls and the `.htaccess` in our root folder is as follows

```
Options +Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

and `.htaccess` in `frontend/web/` is as follows

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

and `main.php` from `frontend/config/` is as follows

```
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);
use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
 //  'defaultRoute' => 'site/program',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' =>$baseUrl,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [

            ]
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

and now the problem is that default actions that come while creating project are working like `login`, `signup`, `about`, `contact` and `defaultroute` are working. Other than these, any new action is not working and giving the error as `yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request`
where did we made wrong, why `defaultroute` is working and other action in same controller is not working. Please suggest us in right way.

Comment: why are you use this htaccess ?

Comment: if you want achieve pretty url in localhost you can make virtualhost in local, if you want achieve or remove frontend/web in server you should make some changes

Comment: if you are on local system, create virtual host that point to every app inside the advance app i.e `frontend/web`, `backend/web`, `api/web` e.t.c and start the actual work rather than wasting your time on on configuring it via `.htaccess`

Comment: when the action name is in lowercase, working but if we get any capitals in the action name doesn't works. like `actionContactmenu` works where as `actionContactMenu` is doesn't working what is the reason for it let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the action name is in lowercase, working but if we get any capitals in the action name doesn't works. like actionContactmenu works where as actionContactMenu is doesn't working what is the reason for it let us know....

For this you have to call it contact-menu and not contactmenu.